# "Sleep" buttons missing from modern keyboards

Tags: keyboard

I went to Best Buy to look at some keyboards. I also looked online at Amazon. I noticed that none of the keyboards I looked at have a "Sleep" button, whereas they were once very common. Why is this the case? Other keys, such as the multimedia keys, are still present on many of them. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that the sleep button got pressed more often as an accident and most people don't like that.

It seems to be a rarely used button, so taking up a lot of valuable keyboard space that can be used for another multi-purpose or customizable button.

Anyway, you can always add a custom shortcut to replace the missing sleep button, like a hard-to-accidentally-press button combination. Something like CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+F8 for example that's not used for anything else.

Comment: I need one for my aging mother who is used to having a dedicated sleep button.

Comment: Could look for a used keyboard with a sleep button. Local for-sale ads, Craigslist, maybe eBay, there are a few commercials for sites & apps lately, or whichever is most popular in your area. If price is no object, [this one's $164 US](https://www.amazon.com/Das-Keyboard-Ultimate-Mechanical-DAS4KULTMBLU/dp/B00JKQSGWE/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8) and says it has a dedicated sleep button.

Comment: I got some from Goodwill in the past, but lately haven't seen any.